# How to swap clipboard contents for current selection in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, selection, clipboard, swap

Does anyone know of a *simple* way to swap whatever is currently in my clipboard with the current mouse selection?

So lets say my clipboard has the text `Foo` in it.

On a line of code `public void DoBar() { ...` I have `Bar` selected

I'd like a simple key combination that changes `DoBar()` to `DoFoo()` and leaves me with the text `Bar"`in the clipboard (so that if I was to press CTRL-V it would paste `Bar`).

Note: I don't want to have to fiddle with anything graphical (i.e. clipboard switcher, paste ring). I'm just after a simple key-combination (so CTRL-X: Cut, CTRL-C: Copy, CTRL-V: Paste, CTRL-B?: Swap)

Bonus points for a general solution that works throughout Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you didn't want a solution that involved installing anything, but I landed on this page with the same question, so I decided to post an answer ( that does include a gui )

install AutoHotKey!

see http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/15-clipboard-hotkey-functions/

Kind regards

Ward

Comment: I've been an AHK user for years, and never thought to have a "swap" script. This one works perfectly, and should be marked as the correct answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No generic solution for this exists, so sorry: I anticipate disappointment.

You might be able to build a Visual Studio plugin with an implementation of this, but it isn't a standard solution on any platform besides maybe Vi/Vim or Emacs (and even then I'm not sure).